# What are black-hole ocean eddies?

Tags: ocean, oceanography, coriolis, eddies

How are they formed? Why are they so stable? What finally breaks them apart and what is their typical lifespan? Why are fluid particles trapped inside it and advected towards the center? How do they affect transport of particulate matter and heat in the ocean?

Comment: I think black-hole eddy is a misnomer coming from a study by Haller & Beron-Vera (http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2352). I personally think they are just sensationalized.

Comment: Fair point, it seems like everything that sounds cool in science nowadays is bound to be sensationalized. But regardless of nomenclature, such features (i.e. very strong eddies) do exist and play an important role in the ocean.

Comment: Popularized partially by Big Bang  Season 6 Episode:24

Comment: You seem to be saying "Someone please write an essay on this phenomenon." However, single, specific questions based on some research by the OP seem to get answered more readily.